# Forms authentication - building the solution forces login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I've recently picked up an `ASP.NET` project and have noticed that each time I build the solution I'm logged out of the website. I'm pretty sure I've prevented this in the past with something in the `web.config` that ensures it maintains a consistent authentication cookie but I can't remember what it is and I'm not finding a great deal on Google.

The site uses forms authentication and `ASP.NET MVC 3`.

This is what my web.config currently looks like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="AuthCookie" loginUrl="~/account/sign-in" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Any advice would be greatly received.

Thanks

Comment: I am not able to recall what exactly I did in one of my projects, but did you try using auth ticket based on URI. `forms cookieless="UseUri"`

Comment: Tried adding the timeout property? `<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="UserAuth" loginUrl="~/Accounts/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>`

Comment: Sadly I have tried both of these but still no luck.

Comment: Are you running this on full IIS or IIS Express?  If on full IIS, what's the application pool running as (Network Service, application pool identity, etc.)?  Additionally, if on full IIS, what version of Windows is this?